# Как исправить кодировку, чтобы выводились русскоязычные данные?

Tags: кодировка, utf-8

С помощью Scanner считываю путь до файла, потом эти данные обрабатываю с помощью стримов и вывожу обработанные данные в консоль. Пример кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Your File Path Here Or Input exit To End The Program: ");
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String path = input.nextLine();
        List<Address> addresses = UserPathHandler.readFileWithEnds(path);
        StatisticsService.countingDuplicates(addresses);
        StatisticsService.countingFloorInCities(addresses);
        if (path.equals("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Program Close");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Данные выводятся, но в некорректном формате. Русскоязычные символы заменяются на символы вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю что это проблема кодировки, но не могу ее пока решить - поставил везде UTF-8 и не помогло. До UTF-16 тоже расширял и не помогло, с Windows-1251 точно так же

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также добавлял самой первой строкой String encoding = "UTF-8"; и потом передавал в Scanner вторым параметром, но тоже не помогло. Что еще можно попробовать?

Answer (score 0):

Помогло добавление строки `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в файл по пути: `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options`